# SQLite-Net Extensions Compatibility with SQLite-Net PCL (note no period)

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library, sqlite-net-extensions

Basically my question boils down to if [SQLite-Net Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) ([NuGet Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions/)) is compatible with Frank A. Krueger's [SQLite-net PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/1.1.1). As I understand it, at some point Oystein Krog created a fork to improve things in the past (possibly before Frank updated things?), so [SQLite.Net PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/) came into existence.

Now that there's an "official" `PCL` version by Frank, I'd like to stick to it instead of the fork. However, it's unclear if `SQLite-Net Extensions` actually only supports the fork or not. The site says it supports `SQLite-net` but the dependencies say `SQLite.net`. Any clarification for my (and future people's) sake would be extremely appreciated!!!

Edit: I know that "SQLite-Net PCL" is just the name of the NuGet package, not actually a standalone PCL. I have this (without SQLite-Net Extensions) fully working in my code within an actual PCL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's already a prerelease version (last updated on Saturday, August 13, 2016) for SQLite.Net Extensions-PCL (2.0.0-alpha1) that depends on sqlite-net-pcl (>= 1.1.2) from Frank A. Krueger

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions/2.0.0-alpha1

Answer (score 2):

According to [SQLite-Net Extensions documentation](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) there is a flavor which is compatible with Frank A. Krueger's library but there is no nuget package that depends on [Frank A. Krueger's nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net)

There is  [SQLite.Net Extensions-MvvmCross](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions-MvvmCross/) package which doesn't depend on SQLite.Net PCL but it depends on [MvvmCross SQLite plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Community.Plugin.Sqlite/) which is unlisted from nuget.

> SQLite-Net Extensions is provided in three different flavours,
>   depending on the SQLite-Net version that you are using:
>
> - SQLite-Net PCL version (also as NuGet package)
> - SQLite.Net.Async-PCL version (also as NuGet package)
> - MvvmCross SQLite Community version (also as NuGet package)
> - SQLite-Net standard version (also as NuGet package)

Comment: Yeah the problem is, that first bullet point points to SQLite.Net PCL not SQLite-Net PCL. However the sentences following those bullets point to potentially using the NuGet originally for SQLite.Net PCL and just referencing it. This is why I'm wanting clarification.

Comment: @Steven_BDawg: Looks like it supports Frank A. Krueger's version but there is no nuget package. You should probably recompile it yourself.

Comment: Seems like it... Any links (whether on SO or not) that could help me do that? I'm still transitioning to VS and C# from Android and am having to learn new things like this along the way lol.

Comment: @Steven_BDawg: Clone the repo locally and compile it like any other VS project.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there's a little confusion here, because Frank Krueger nuget package is **not** a PCL. You can't deploy a PCL library depending on a platform-specific library. Therefore you won't find a SQLite-Net Extensions package that uses that platform specific SQLite.Net nuget package.

However, you can just [download the SQLite-Net Extension sources](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/downloads) and copy the source files to your project. If you [take a look at the sources](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/9b65308fa6a95cbc9fd9dce8c222efa5c1b8ff7b/SQLiteNetExtensions/Extensions/ReadOperations.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#ReadOperations.cs-18), you'll see that, unless defined otherwise, it will use the Frank's `SQLite` package.

```
#if USING_MVVMCROSS
using SQLiteConnection = Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite.ISQLiteConnection;
#elif PCL
using SQLite.Net;
using SQLite.Net.Attributes;
#else
using SQLite;
#endif
```

I haven't tested in some time, but it should work.

However I'd recommend you to stick to `SQLite-Net PCL` as it's actively maintained and currently evolving with more features (like asynchronous operations).

Comment: The link I provided (https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/1.1.1) is Frank's nuget package of SQLite-Net FOR a PCL. It was last updated this past January (2016). To use it, you install that same nuget on the PCL as well as the device specific project(s). This nuget by itself is working perfectly fine in my current solution, which is a PCL and a Windows project. Soon I'll add Xamarin.Android and I'm confident it will work there too. However, if I can add SQLite-Net Extensions to the mix, life would be even better.

Comment: To be clear, I know that the link provided is not a PCL by itself. Rather, it's just the actual name of the NuGet when you pull it up on the manager or go to the site.